# Wait at waypoint for amount of time in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a waypoint system in a Unity 2D project where the GameObject will follow each waypoint in order and then repeat the process, i am wanting the GameObject to stop at each point for a fixed amount of time and i thought i could achieve this using a coroutine but not entirely sure of how to achieve this, what i have done so far is create a coroutine called WaitAtPoint and then call this on each waypoint movement but to no avail, not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
public class BrainBoss : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField]
Transform[] waypoints;

[SerializeField]
float moveSpeed = 2f;

int waypointIndex = 0;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    transform.position = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Move();
}

void Move()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
        waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(transform.position == waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitAtPoint());
        waypointIndex += 1;
    }

    if(waypointIndex == waypoints.Length)
    {
        waypointIndex = 1;
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitAtPoint()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling Move every update and you could also be calling that StartCoroutine multiple times so i suggest using a variable to see if you should even update the movement

```
public class BrainBoss : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
Transform[] waypoints;

[SerializeField]
float moveSpeed = 2f;

int waypointIndex = 0;
private bool shouldMove = true;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
    transform.position = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    if (this.shouldMove) {
        Move();
    }
}

void Move() {
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,
        waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position == waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position) {
        StartCoroutine(WaitAtPoint(3));
        waypointIndex += 1;
    }

    if (waypointIndex == waypoints.Length) {
        waypointIndex = 1;
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitAtPoint(int seconds) {
    this.shouldMove = false;
    int counter = seconds;
    while (counter > 0) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        counter--;
    }

    this.shouldMove = true;
}
```

}

Comment: Perfect, using a variable to check if should move makes sense now and it went straight over my head, never thought to loop with a counter either i like this setup it works well, so much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simble bool flag to know if you should move or not. In Move (or Update), check for that bool to know if you should move or not.

In WaitAtPoint, set the bool (like shouldWait) to true, then back to false after the WaitForSecond !

Answer (score 2):

Well, your `WaitAtPoint` is not doing an awful lot at the moment. This is because it is waiting inside the IEnumerator, not where you are calling it.

There are various ways to tackle this, but I would suggest using a `callback` on your IEnumerator which is executed after the waiting time.

Like this:

```
private bool isWaiting;

void Update() {
    if (!isWaiting) {
        Move();
    }
}

void Move()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
        waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(transform.position == waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitAtPoint(() => 
        {
            // All code that should be executed after waiting here.
            waypointIndex += 1;
        }));

    }

    if(waypointIndex == waypoints.Length)
    {
        waypointIndex = 1;
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitAtPoint(Action callback)
{
    isWaiting = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    callback.Invoke();
    isWaiting = false;
}
```

Comment: I like the concept, but if you start that in Update like OP does, wouldnt you start a ton of coroutines? Not like OP doesnt do that anyway, yet ...

Comment: Yes you are right, i missed that. So i guess you'd need a boolean flag in the current structure anyhow. Updated the answer